# SQL - updating both tables when a user registers

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm trying to create a booking application in Android. I have a mysql database that I connect to.

At the moment I have two tables - `Customer Details` and `Customer login` with the `p_ID` in login as a `primary key` and the same `p_ID` being the `foriegn key` in the details table. This value is set to auto increment every time someone new registers. However I dont understand how to link these together. Since they are unique and auto incremented I can't see the way to link them without filling one in manually.

so my question is: Am I doing it completely wrong? Should I be manually setting the IDs? What is the correct way to link a Login table to general customer details when for example a user registers, how to add to both tables while maintaining a matching ID ?

For example:

`login` table:

```
P_ID (PK) | username | password
-------------------------------
1         | me       | me123
```

`details` table:

```
name | age | location | P_ID (FK)
---------------------------------
john | 40  | UK       | 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DB structure is OK, but you cannot insert data in both tables with single SQL query. Instead of that, you can use transaction together with `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function:

```
BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO login (`username`, `password`)
        VALUES('me', 'me123');
    INSERT INTO datails (`P_ID`, `name`, `age`, `location`) 
        VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'john', '40', 'UK');
COMMIT;
```

Since your primary ID is autoincremental in your `login` table, you don't need to care about it at all with such approach. Foreign key in `details` table must not be autoincremental, but just normal integer.